# AngularJs Service/Provider Getter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have a resource that everytime it is being used it evaluate it by fetching data from a cookie and return it as a JSON object, **so I can use it this way**:

```
var data = $userData
```

**Note when getting the parameter will get updated data.**

I can do that with a function, but then I can access it only like this:**

```
$userData.SomeFunc()
```

I can do that with a getter property, **but then I can access it only like this:**

```
$userData.SomeData
```

This is how I know I can implement it with a getter property:

```
proGamersApp.factory('$userData', ['cookiesStorage', function (cookiesStorage) {

    var userData = {
        get SomeData() {
            return cookiesStorage.getCookie();
        }  
    };

    return userData;
}]);
```

Anyone knows how can I accomplish it? I've tried doing it by factory or service but with no success, since its evaluated only at the first call.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `$` in your own variables. The `$` is to mark AngularJS's own private stuff.

As to how you could create a service that's accessible through its property name, you could try this:

```js
proGamersApp.factory('userData', ['cookiesStorage', function(cookiesStorage) {

  var userData = {}

  // this function immediately executes itself and 
  // calculates the value that you wanna return
  // once it is loaded
  userData.someProperty = (function() {
    // do stuff here
    var val = 1
    return val
  })()

  userData.simplerProperty = 3

  return userData
}]);
```

Now when you ask for this service some where else, you'll be able to access its properties like so:

`userData.someProperty // will return 1`

`userData.simplerProperty // will return 3`

Comment: Have a look at my last example, I would like to retrieve all the updated data (bsaed on cookies) everytime I directly call $userData without properties, so I everywhere in the app I will be able to retrieve it like this: var data = $cache.